# Joins in SQL for retriving data from two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql, join

There are two tables A and B. You are retreiving data from both tables where all rows from B table and only matching rows from A table should be displayed. Which of the following types of joins will you apply between A and B tables?

```
- Inner join
- Left outer join
- Right outer join
- Self join
```

Comment: Another question from eLance tests from this user...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use left outer hoin or right outer join.

For example, the following satisfy your requirement.

```
select * from tableB
Left outer join tableA
on tableB.ID= tableA.ID
```

Or

```
select * from tableA
Right outer join tableB
on tableA.ID= tableB.ID
```

Better way to understand:

[image]

Comment: this one of the best article read and best way to understand about joins

Answer (score 1):

Easy, I would go with (B).

```
SELECT * FROM B x
LEFT JOIN A y
  on x.someColName = y.someColname
```

EDIT: can also use Right join

```
SELECT * FROM A x
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B y
  on x.someColName = y.someColname
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, but it's dead simple enough that I'll just say that you're asking for `B LEFT JOIN A`.

Answer (score 0):

Join Left

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Possible reasons for down vote: 'Join Left' isn't one of the options, though 'Left outer join' is implied; 'Right outer join' is an equally valid answer.